# Why doesn't this Racket code terminate?

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm reading about lazy evaluation and having trouble understanding a basic example they gave.

```
#lang racket
(define (bad-if x y z)
  (if x y z))
(define (factorial-wrong x)
  (bad-if (= x 0)
          1
          (* x (factorial-wrong (- x 1)))))

(factorial-wrong 4)
```

I'm a little confused as to why this program never terminates. I know the following code works just fine:

```
(define (factorial x)
  (if (= x 0)
      1
      (* x (factorial (- x 1)))))

(factorial 4)
```

So I'm assuming it has something to do with scope. I tried step by step debugging and factorial-wrong executes the recursion function even when x is mapped to 0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard `if`

```
(if test-expr then-expr else-expr)
```

will only evaluate **either** `then-expr` **or** `else-expr`, depending on `test-expr`,  because this `if` is either a *special form* or a *syntactic extension* based on a special form, which means it doesn't follow the normal evaluation rules.

`bad-if`, on the other hand, is a standard procedure. In that case, Scheme first evaluates **both** expressions since they are parameters to the procedure `bad-if` *before* actually executing `bad-if`. So, even for x = 0, `(* x (factorial -1))` will be evaluated, which will in turn evaluate `(* x (factorial -2))` and so on, in an endless loop.

Comment: so the `if` statements are behaving differently in the two examples? any idea why that is so?

Comment: No the if statements behave exactly in the same way. The difference comes from the fact that you call bad-if which is a procedure. It's the procedure calling mechanism which forces the additional evaluation.

Comment: To further note the fact that `if` is not a procedure, if you enter in `bad-if` at the REPL, you should see something like `#<procedure:bad-if>`, whereas if you enter `if`, you should get a `bad-syntax` error. The same holds true for `or` and `and`, since those two forms have special rules for when to evaluate their arguments as well.

Answer (score 4):

Use the stepper!

To be more specific:

- Snip the #lang racket off the top of your program
- Change the language level to "Intermediate Student"
- Click on the Step button. Watch carefully to see where things go off the rails.